# version one api java sdk save

Tags: java, versionone

I am trying to update a task name using the latest Java SDK (com.versionone.apiclient.V1Connector).
 I am able to open a connection and execute a query and get data from the server successfully. Now that i have the task Oid, i am trying to update an attribute on it and it is throwing following error -

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
```

Debugging in my Eclipse shows it is constructing the xml for the rest api call correctly. However i am unable to figure out why it fails.

```
Oid taskid = service.getOid("Task:14513272");
IAssetType updtaskType = service.getMeta().getAssetType("Task");
IAttributeDefinition updNameAttr = updtaskType.getAttributeDefinition("Name"); 
Query updQuery = new Query(taskid);
updQuery.getSelection().add(updNameAttr);
QueryResult updResult = service.retrieve(updQuery);
Asset tasktoupd = updResult.getAssets()[0];
String newValue = "VersionOne developer trainign";
tasktoupd.setAttributeValue(updNameAttr, newValue);
service.save(tasktoupd);
```

At this point the error is seen as -

```
SAX Error : Task/14513272
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
```

Comment: If you show the XML that is generated, it might be easier to help you.

Comment: On adding debug points on Service.class in package com.versionone.apiclient, i can see the data string (xml) and path are set as -   data = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Asset id="Task:14513272"><Attribute act="set" name="Name">Rajesh salesforce developer trainign</Attribute></Asset>    and path = Task/14513272

Comment: Was able to execute your code above just as it is, the only difference being the task OID used in the first line. On what line of code are you getting this error? Might be helpful to see the full stack trace.